# VMWare ESX - Hot add RAM does not showing the new value inside Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, hotswap

I have VMware ESXi, 6.7.0, 17098360 server in my environment. Recently I tried Hot Add RAM with one of my Microsoft Windows Server 2016 VMs.

I successfully increased from 16 GB to 24 GB but inside the guest OS console it's not showing as 24 GB still the old value 16 GB.

Why is this issue occurring?

- No any RAM limit inside VMWare
- Installed latest VMWare Tools
- No any vNUMA issue

Comment: Presumably the VM has the latest vmtools installed?

Comment: Yeap already installed I have checked it inside System Information. device guard virtualization based security : Not Enabled

Comment: Which edition of Windows server are you running in your VM? Standard, Enterprise, Datacenter?

Comment: Which edition of Windows server are you running in your VM? Standard

Answer (score 1):

### Background from my Knowledge

Hot-Adding Memory or CPU never worked for me on any Windows VM's due to the past Years.
A Scheduled Downtime for an Off/On was always Required

Reference: [VMware KB52584](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/52584)

### Original Statement:

> Virtualization Based Security (VBS) is a new feature introduced in
> Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016.  vSphere supports running Windows
> with VBS enabled starting in the vSphere 6.7 release. However, hot-add
> memory and CPU will not operate for Windows virtual machines when
> Virtualization Based Security (VBS) is enabled in the OS.

### Solution

> To resolve this issue, power off the virtual machine to make Memory and CPU changes.

### Remarks

> This affect mostly also the Hot-Add of CPU's imho.

#### Reference for Other Links

> Microsoft page: [Virtualization Based Security (VBS)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/oem-vbs) in Gerneral

This Answer should be more Generic, but its also Specific to your Question also ;)

I hope i could help you with your Question and would be glad if you accept and upvote it :-)

Comment: thanks but I have checked it inside System Information. device guard virtualization based security  : Not Enabled

Comment: in my opinion it does not matter, it only works for me eith off and on switching the vm